# Using IF..ELSE in UPDATE (SQL server 2005 and/or ACCESS 2007)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to set a query like below:

```
UPDATE XXXXXX
IF column A = 1 then set column B = 'Y' 
ELSE IF column A = 2 then set column C = 'Y' 
ELSE IF column A = 3 then set column D = 'Y'
```

and so on and so forth...

I am able to do this using multiple queries but was wondering, if I can do it in just 1 statement instead.

Answer (score 52):

this should work

```
update table_name
  set column_b = case
                  when column_a = 1 then 'Y'
                  else null
                 end,
  set column_c = case
                  when column_a = 2 then 'Y'
                  else null
                 end,
  set column_d = case
                  when column_a = 3 then 'Y'
                  else null
                 end
where
 conditions
```

the question is why would you want to do that...you may want to rethink the data model. you can replace `null` with whatever you want.

Comment: There are 2 extra "set" as I tried in SQL 2008. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can use `CASE`

```
UPDATE table 
SET columnB = CASE fieldA 
        WHEN columnA=1 THEN 'x' 
        WHEN columnA=2 THEN 'y' 
        ELSE 'z' 
      END 
WHERE columnC = 1
```

Comment: can anybody tell what fieldA supposed to be here

Comment: @PriyankaArora that's what I'm wondering.